# how to query all the columns based on condition in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a function like this :

```
  def dbquery(find_by_entry, start_date, end_date):
          start_date = str(datetime.strptime(start_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')))
          new_end_date = str(datetime.strptime(end_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')) + timedelta(days=1))
          data = Analytics.query.filter(Analytics.created_date.between(start_date, new_end_date)).filter_by(id=find_by_entry).order_by(desc('created_date')).all()
          data_schema = AnalyticsSchema(many=True).dump(data)
          return data_schema
```

When I execute the above function, It will take arguments like:

```
        dbquery('1', '2020-04-20', '2020-06-20)
```

and It will return the below out put:

```
         [{'id:1' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:1' , 'name' :'YYY'}, ...]
```

but If I pass multiple values for find_by_entry like:

```
        ['1','2', '3', '4']
```

I can put "data" variable inside a loop, but here is the problem, for "id: 1", there is a possibility of multiple records or a single record, but I want everything in single list:

I have tried the below code for above requirement:

```
     def dbquery(find_by_entry, start_date, end_date):
          empty_list = []
          start_date = str(datetime.strptime(start_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')))
          new_end_date = str(datetime.strptime(end_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')) + timedelta(days=1))
          for i in find_by_entry:
               data = Analytics.query.filter(Analytics.created_date.between(start_date, new_end_date)).filter_by(id=i).order_by(desc('created_date')).all()
               data_schema = AnalyticsSchema(many=True).dump(data)
               empty_list.append(data_schema)
          return empty_list
```

I am calling a function like below

```
     dbquery(['1','2', '3', '4'], '2020-04-20', '2020-06-20)
```

Current output:

```
      [[{'id:1' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:1' , 'name' :'YYY'}, ...], [{'id:2' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:2' , 'name' :'YYY'}, ...], [{'id:3' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:3' , 'name' :'YYY'}, ...], [{'id:4' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:4' , 'name' :'YYY'}, ...]]
```

Expected output:

```
       [{'id:1' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:1' , 'name' :'YYY'}, {'id:2' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:2' , 'name' :'YYY'}, {'id:3' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:3' , 'name' :'YYY'}, {'id:4' , 'name' :'XXX' }, {'id:4' , 'name' :'YYY'} ]
```

**Note:**

```
Here "id" is not a primary key.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to solve this. Firstly, you're appending as list instead of extending it, so the following should work with the structure:

```py
def dbquery(find_by_entry, start_date, end_date):
      empty_list = []
      start_date = str(datetime.strptime(start_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')))
      new_end_date = str(datetime.strptime(end_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')) + timedelta(days=1))
      for i in find_by_entry:
           data = Analytics.query.filter(Analytics.created_date.between(start_date, new_end_date)).filter_by(id=i).order_by(desc('created_date')).all()
           data_schema = AnalyticsSchema(many=True).dump(data)
           empty_list.extend(data_schema) # Note here
      return empty_list
```

The second thing is you can easily do this all in one query, which is faster, easier to understand, and better practice:

```py
def dbquery(find_by_entry, start_date, end_date):
      start_date = str(datetime.strptime(start_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')))
      new_end_date = str(datetime.strptime(end_date, format('%Y-%m-%d')) + timedelta(days=1))
      for i in find_by_entry:
      data = Analytics.query.filter(
          Analytics.created_date.between(start_date, new_end_date),
          Analytics.id.in_(find_by_entry)
      ).order_by('id', desc('created_date')).all()
      data_schema = AnalyticsSchema(many=True).dump(data)
      return data_schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try add more fields which you need return in a file analytics_schema ?? In file analytics_schema look like this:

```
class AnalyticsSchema(Schema):
 class Meta:
    strict = True
    ordered = True

 id = fields.Int()
 name = fields.String() 


analytics_schema = AnalyticsSchema()
```

and then you can use like that:

```
analytics_schema.dump(data).data
```